# Linux Device Driver: IRQ 1 and IRQ 23

Tags: c, linux-kernel, keyboard, linux-device-driver

Some days ago, I posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47652391/linux-device-driver-error-for-the-keyboard-interrupt-handling/47653554?noredirect=1#comment82379998_47653554), asking how to safely develop a keyboard interrupt handler.
Digging more into the suggested answer, made me to find out that basically my default keyboard handler is not set into IRQ 1. This is because `cat /proc/interrupts` and `watch -n1 cat /proc/interrupts` both highlight that IRQ 1 is not responsible for the keyboard handling. Besides, since I have my keyboard and mouse, both, connected via USB, I found out that IRQ 23 is responsible for two USB devices. Then I modified the code a little. Whenever I set my handler to IRQ 23 simply by `free_irq(23, (void*)irq_handler)`, I can get the interrupt fired upon any key pressed/released and any mouse movement. So, basically IRQ 23 triggers in response to any keyboard and mouse events. Here I am not able to find which key is pressed because both ports `0x60` and `0x64` always report the same values 156 and 28 respectively under any mentioned action (key press, key release, mouse click, mouse move, etc.).

There are two things. 1) why IRQ 1 is not responsible for the keyboard interrupt handling, and 2) if IRQ 23 is responsible, why getting values from ports `0x60` and `0x64` cannot resolve what I expected from my code posted in the above link?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: If you are using USB keyboard then the kernel module code that you have posted will not work. You need to write a kernel module for USB HID. Better look into implementation of usbmon kernel module.

Comment: @Gaurav Thanks again for your response. Now, there is a new chapter to think about.

Comment: If you want to keep things simple, you could try to disable USB subsystem in kernel and use usb legacy mode. In this case ps/2 host kernel driver will work (this driver is pretty simple) .

Comment: You knowledge of IRQ concept in Linux is blurry. Linux operates with IRQ domains and internal numbering. It's quite different from HW, though in most simple cases it tries to make them 1-on-1.

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh Did you end up working this out? I am in a similar situation.

Comment: @Rein F: yes. It was successful in my case.